# get an ordered list of objects from 2 maps sharing same properties in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, data-structures

**I have a map with order(rank) I expect**

sortedMap{deviceId:rank}:

```
{0:"id0"},
{1,"id1"},
{2:"id2"},
{3:"id3"},
```

**having another map that needs to be sorted**

```
{"id3":object3},
{"id1":object1},
{"id0":object0},
{"id2":object2}
```

**I expected having list like**

```
{object0},
{object1},
{object2},
{object3}
```

i tried with code like below, but it seems wrong with the list adding part in my code, and i don't know any better solution for it:

```
    private List<MyObject> getSortedResultList(Map<String, Integer> sortedMap, Map<String, Object> toSortMap) {
    List<MyObject> sortedResultList = null;
    for (Integer rank : sortedMap.keySet()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedMap.size(); i++) {
            sortedResultList.add(i, (MyObject) toSortMap.get(sortedMap.get(rank)));
        }
    }
    return sortedResultList;
}
```

Tried searched online for hours, got no clues to solve it because of my weak datastructure knowledge and decided asking for help from here, thanks advanced if any suggestions could be raised.

Comment: Are you sure `sortedMap` or it's keyset is sorted ?

Comment: @Eklavya got the sortedMap using stream from an ordered list, i tested with some data i have in DB, by far, it's okay to me

Comment: Do you collect in LinkedHashMap/TreeMap when collecting from an ordered list ?, either order will not be preserved. And the inner loop is unnecessary , you can do `sortedResultList.add((MyObject) toSortMap.get(sortedMap.get(rank)));`

Comment: @Eklavya thanks,got it, i'll change the streaming process into  Collectors.toMap(k->k,v->v, (k1,k2)->k2,LinkedHashMap::new)

Comment: @Eklavya   Sorry to bother you repeatedly, i checked on Collectors.toMap(k->k,v->v, (k1,k2)->k2,LinkedHashMap::new)  and couldn't figure out how to fit in my case, given with list<myobject> with properties "id" and "rank"

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
List<Object> sortedList = sortedMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .map(entry -> toSortMap.get(entry.getKey()))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First the entries are sorted, then we get the corresponding object, then we filter out the null values and finally we collect everything in a list.

Answer (score 0):

If `sortedMap` is sorted by key (e.g. it's a `TreeMap`) it should suffice to build the list sorted by the `sortedMap`'s values:

```java
private static List<MyObject> getSortedResultList(TreeMap<Integer, String> sortedMap, Map<String, MyObject> toSortMap) {

    return sortedMap.values().stream()
                    .map(key -> toSortMap.get(key))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If `sortedMap` needs to be sorted additionally:

```java
private static List<MyObject> getSortedResultList2(Map<Integer, String> sortedMap, Map<String, MyObject> toSortMap) {

    return sortedMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                    .map(entry -> toSortMap.get(entry.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Test:

```java
Map<Integer, String> sorted = new TreeMap<>(Map.of(1, "id1", 0, "id0", 3, "id3", 2, "id2"));
Map<String, MyObject> toSort = Map.of(
    "id3", new MyObject("object3"), "id1", new MyObject("object1"),
    "id0", new MyObject("object0"), "id2", new MyObject("object2")
);

System.out.println(getSortedResultList(sorted, toSort));

System.out.println(getSortedResultList2(sorted, toSort));
```

Both outputs identical:

```
[MyObject(field=object0), MyObject(field=object1), MyObject(field=object2), MyObject(field=object3)]
[MyObject(field=object0), MyObject(field=object1), MyObject(field=object2), MyObject(field=object3)]
```